# Update Table to include calculated percentage

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have the following simplified table:

```
╔══════════╦═══════════╗═══════════╗═══════════╗
║ Dough    ║ Material  ║ PerCharge ║ Perc      ║
╠══════════╬═══════════╣═══════════╣═══════════╣
║ DG10001  ║ GR002152  ║ 2,00      ║           ║ 
║ DG10001  ║ GR000133  ║ 9,00      ║           ║ 
║ DG10001  ║ GR000133  ║ 9,00      ║           ║ 
║ DG10002  ║ GR002152  ║ 2,50      ║           ║ 
╚══════════╩═══════════╝═══════════╝═══════════╝
```

Dough-Material is a one on many relation, PerCharge is the raw material weigth used per container.

I want to calculate the percentage for every individual row based on the total used for each unique dough.

I've used the following to calculate the percentage

```
SELECT D.Dough
       ,Material
       ,PerCharge
       ,PerCharge/Total as Percentage
  FROM 
(Select Dough
       ,sum(PerCharge) as Total
From [PP_Materials].[dbo].[Deegregels]

group by Dough
) as D

left join

(SELECT Dough
      ,Material
     ,PerCharge
FROM [PP_Materials].[dbo].[Deegregels]
) as D2
On D.Dough = D2.Dough

order by D.Dough
```

Now I only need to update the original table to include this calculated percentage, but I can't figure out how to formulate the update statement.

Any help you can give is appreciated.

EDIT: Result for the simplified example

```
╔══════════╦═══════════╗═══════════╗═══════════╗
║ Dough    ║ Material  ║ PerCharge ║ Perc      ║
╠══════════╬═══════════╣═══════════╣═══════════╣
║ DG10001  ║ GR002152  ║ 2,00      ║     10%   ║ 
║ DG10001  ║ GR000133  ║ 9,00      ║     45%   ║ 
║ DG10001  ║ GR000133  ║ 9,00      ║     45%   ║ 
║ DG10002  ║ GR002152  ║ 2,50      ║     10%   ║ 
╚══════════╩═══════════╝═══════════╝═══════════╝
```

Comment: What is your expected resultset here?

Comment: Added sample result, on average each Dough has 6 Materials so didn't include it in the simplified version.

Comment: I assume 10% should actually be 100%. Otherwise that data doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also wrap it into a cte

```
with updatestatement as  (SELECT D.Dough
       ,Material
       ,PerCharge
       ,PerCharge/Total as Percentage
  FROM 
(Select Dough
       ,sum(PerCharge) as Total
From [dbo].[Deegregels]

group by Dough
) as D

left join

(SELECT Dough
      ,Material
     ,PerCharge
FROM [dbo].[Deegregels]
) as D2
On D.Dough = D2.Dough
)

update b
set perc = a.percentage

from updatestatement a inner join dbo.[Deegregels] b on a.dough = b.dough and a.material = b.material
```

Comment: Thanks, I also tried using a cte but was unable to work it into the update statement. This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

A much more succinct version:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO
--Create sample table and data
CREATE TABLE #Dough (Dough varchar(10),
                     Material varchar(10),
                     PerCharge decimal(5,2),
                     Perc decimal(3,2));

INSERT INTO #Dough (Dough,
                    Material,
                    PerCharge)
VALUES ('DG10001','GR002152',2.00), 
       ('DG10001','GR000133',9.00), 
       ('DG10001','GR000133',9.00), 
       ('DG10002','GR002152',2.50);
GO
--The solution

WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT D.Dough, D.Material, D.PerCharge, Perc,
           PerCharge / SUM(PerCharge) OVER (PARTITION BY Dough) AS NewPerc
    FROM #Dough D)
UPDATE CTE
SET Perc = NewPerc
GO
--Check the data
SELECT *
FROM #Dough
GO
--Clean up
DROP TABLE #Dough;
```

No need to scan the table twice, when you can use a Window Function.

Comment: Thanks alot, I used the CTE answer provided earlier to update it but this solution seems alot cleaner, going to try to understand the logic now.

Comment: @A.vanEsveld you're welcome. i obviously had a mental blipp, as I did reference the table twice. I've changed that now so that it doesn't (and it's more succinct).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Dough
(
    Dough VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    PerCharge DECIMAL(10,2) NULL,
    [Percentage] DECIMAL(10,2) NULL
)

INSERT INTO #Dough
VALUES
('DG10001',2,NULL),('DG10001',9,NULL),('DG10001',9,NULL),('DG10002',2,NULL)

SELECT *
FROM #Dough

;WITH Total AS
(
    SELECT   Dough
            ,Total = SUM(PerCharge)
    FROM #Dough
    GROUP BY Dough
)
UPDATE D1
SET [Percentage] = D1.PerCharge/T1.Total
FROM #Dough D1
JOIN Total  T1 ON D1.Dough = T1.Dough
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the direction I was working in, it does give an error though:
Msg 4418, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Derived table 'D' is not updatable because it contains aggregates, or a DISTINCT or GROUP BY clause, or PIVOT or UNPIVOT operator.

Comment: I edited my answer and simplified your code so that you wont need to use subqueries. I added my test code so that you can use it.

Comment: Yes I have tested it and it runs with no issues and returns the percentage per dough. If you referring to me not including the Material that was by choice.